# Write multi-line output to file w/o creating another buffer

Tags: vim, cat

Sometimes when working on my scripts in vim, I need to create some test data in temporary files, with multi-line content with minimum effort for typing. I tried using the usual

```
cat << EOF ...
```

in the vim command line, but it looks like vim interprets the first `<cr>` as the end of the command:

```
/bin/bash: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOF')
```

Is there some way to enter multi-line input in the command line buffer or maybe another way to write given multi-line data into files w/o exiting vim, running `:sh` or creating new buffers?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the feel the simplest solution is likely typing directly into whatever file you're editing and then visually selecting it with `` v`[ `` or `v{`. Then you can type `:` to operate on the visually selected text and use `:w yourfilename.txt` to write it to a file. Delete the text or hit `u` for undo.

This isn't exactly what you asked for though so here are some other options:

#### Option 1

Abuse `:!tee myfile`. Here you'll be redirected to an instance of tee which will write stdin to stdout as well as to your specified file `myfile`. Things will print twice on the screen and you'll have to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> out of it, but it gets the job done just not exactly how you wanted.

#### Option 2

```
command! -nargs=1 Scratch call Scratch("<args>")
fun! Scratch(args)
    exe 'e ' . a:args
    call feedkeys(":append^M")
endfun
```

This will make a command `:Scratch` that takes a filename and then opens a new buffer of that file name and hacks calling the `:append` command which will append a multi-line string of text to the current buffer. You can end the multi-line string with `.` or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. You would then have to save the buffer and return to the original one though.

> Note that there are no such things as heredocs or multi-line strings in vim command mode. There are however special commands that allow them for scripting languages such as `:py <<EOF` (also ruby, lua, etc.).